# Escape characters getting inserted into database

Tags: mysql, c, database

I am inserting arbitrary binary data into a mysql database MEDIUMBLOB using the below code.  I am writing the same data to a file, from the same program.  I then create a file from the DB contents:

```
select data from table where tag=95 order by date, time into outfile "dbout";
```

I then compare the output written directly to the file to the output in dbout.  There are escape (0x5c, '\') characters before some bytes in the dbout file (e.g. before 0x00).  This garbles the output from the database.  My understanding was that by using a MEDIUMBLOB and prepared statements, I could avoid this problem.  Initially I was using mysql_real_escape_string with a regular INSERT, and having the problem.  Nothing seems to be fixing this.

```
void
insertdb(int16_t *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
{
    int16_t *fwbuf; // I have also tried this as char *fwbuf
    unsigned long i;
    struct tm *info;
    time_t rawtime;
    char dbuf[12];
    char tbuf[12];

    if(fwinitialized==0){
        fwbuf = malloc(CHUNK_SZ);
        fwinitialized = 1;
    }

    if(fwindex + (nmemb*size) + 1 >= CHUNK_SZ || do_exit == 1){
        MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(con);
        MYSQL_BIND param[1];

        time(&rawtime);
        info = localtime(&rawtime);
        snprintf(dbuf, 16, "%d-%02d-%02d", 1900+info->tm_year, 1+info->tm_mon, info->tm_mday);
        snprintf(tbuf, 16, "%02d:%02d:%02d", info->tm_hour, info->tm_min, info->tm_sec);

        char *tmp = "INSERT INTO %s (date, time, tag, data) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, ?)";
        int len = strlen(tmp)+strlen(db_mon_table)+strlen(dbuf)+strlen(tbuf)+MAX_TAG_LEN+1;
        char *sql = (char *) malloc(len);
        int sqllen = snprintf(sql, len, tmp, db_mon_table, dbuf, tbuf, tag);

        if(mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql, strlen(sql)) != 0){
            printf("Unable to create session: mysql_stmt_prepare()\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        memset(param, 0, sizeof(param));
        param[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_MEDIUM_BLOB;
        param[0].buffer = fwbuf;
        param[0].is_unsigned = 0;
        param[0].is_null = 0;
        param[0].length = &fwindex;

        if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, param) != 0){
            printf("Unable to create session: mysql_stmt_bind_param()\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt) != 0){
            printf("Unabel to execute session: mysql_stmt_execute()\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("closing\n");
        mysql_stmt_close(stmt);

        free(sql);
        fwindex = 0;

    } else {
        memcpy((void *) fwbuf+fwindex, (void *) data, nmemb*size);
        fwindex += (nmemb*size);
    }
}
```

So, why the escape characters in the database?  I have tried a couple of combinations of hex/unhex in the program and when creating the file from msyql.  That didn't seem to help either.  Isn't inserting arbitrary binary data into a database be a common thing with a well-defined solution?

P.S. - Is it ok to have prepared statements that open, insert, and close like this, or are prepared statements generally for looping and inserting a bunch of data before closing?

PPS - Maybe this is important to the problem: When I try to use UNHEX like this:

```
select unhex(data) from table where tag=95 order by date, time into outfile "dbout";
```

the output is very short (less than a dozen bytes, truncated for some reason).

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code, least of all which is the negligence to show what `tag` is, and one of the worst is the possible [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) of not allocating space in the string for the string terminator.

Comment: what is the datatype of tag? note that the sizeof(tag) is not a good estimate for the string length representation of the number. if tag is a pointer it will be 8 or 4 bytes (depending on if you are compiling for 32 or 64 bit architecture) no matter the number stored for example the number "1" is only length 1.. Also you have some memory leaks in your program. specifically in you error handling code you do not free the sql or fwbuf before exiting.

Comment: @Rob - Tag is just an int.  Also, if the program exits, I think that sql and fwbuf will be 'freed' by the OS.  But what about my problem of storing arbitrary binary data in a database without escape characters?

Comment: LOL yeah exit would clean up. :) since the whole program would exit. the length point is still valid.

Comment: If `tag` is an `int`, then `sizeof(tag)` might not be enough to store the value in that integer. Remember that on most platforms `int` is just 32 bits (four bytes), so if you have more than four digits then you allocate to little memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Ok I get it.  Thanks.  Now for the DB problem :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `MEDIUMBLOB` can contain any character (even an ASCII `NUL`) MySQL normally escapes the output so you can tell when fields end. You can control this using `ESCAPED BY`. The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). Below is an excerpt. According to the last paragraph below (which I've put in bold), you can entirely disable escaping. I have never tried that, for the reason in the last sentence.

> `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` controls how to write special characters. If the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character is not empty, it is used when necessary to avoid ambiguity as a prefix that precedes following characters on output:
>
> - The `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character
> - The `FIELDS [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY` character
> - The first character of the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY` values
> - `ASCII NUL` (the zero-valued byte; what is actually written following the escape character is `ASCII "0"`, not a zero-valued byte)
>
> The `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, `ENCLOSED BY`, `ESCAPED BY`, or `LINES TERMINATED BY` characters must be escaped so that you can read the file back in reliably. ASCII `NUL` is escaped to make it easier to view with some pagers.
>
> The resulting file does not have to conform to SQL syntax, so nothing else need be escaped.
>
> **If the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` character is empty, no characters are escaped and `NULL` is output as `NULL`, not `\N`.** It is probably not a good idea to specify an empty escape character, particularly if field values in your data contain any of the characters in the list just given.

A better strategy (if you only need one blob in the output file) is `SELECT INTO ... DUMPFILE`, documented on the same page, per the below:

> If you use `INTO DUMPFILE` instead of `INTO OUTFILE`, MySQL writes only one row into the file, without any column or line termination and without performing any escape processing. This is useful if you want to store a BLOB value in a file.